# Calendar events in react native

Tags: react-native, calendar

I'm using the [the react-native-calendar](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars) library to make an agenda where every user can create an event whenever he wants and it'll be displayed to the others. My question is where do I push the event when it's created ? I'm using firebase as database.

Thanks !